# JPA + GAE -> insert not immediately update datastore

Tags: java, google-app-engine, jpa, google-cloud-datastore

i trying develop using :

```
Google App Engine
Data Store 
JPA 
Spring Framework
```

I made a page for listing customer. And below that list i made a form to insert new Customer.

```
Customer List 
<table>
    <c:forEach items="${listCustomer}" var="customer" varStatus="status">
        <tr>
            <td>${customer.id}</td>
            <td>${customer.name}</td>
            <td>${customer.desc}</td>

        </tr>
    </c:forEach>
</table>
New Customer    
<form:form action="add" commandName="customer"
    methodParam="POST">
    <form:input path="name"/>
    <form:input path="desc"/>
    <input type="submit" value="Add" />
</form:form>
```

Controller :

```
@RequestMapping(value="/list", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public String list( ModelMap model) {
    List<Customer> list=CustomerDAO.INSTANCE.listCustomers();
    model.addAttribute("listCustomer",list);
    return "customer";

}

@RequestMapping(value="/add", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public String add( ModelMap model, Customer form) {
    CustomerDAO.INSTANCE.add(form.getName(),form.getDesc());
    List<Customer> list=CustomerDAO.INSTANCE.listCustomers();
    model.addAttribute("listCustomer",list);
    model.addAttribute("customer",new Customer());
    return "customer";
}
```

CustomerDAO

```
public enum CustomerDAO {
INSTANCE;

  public List<Customer> listCustomers() {
    EntityManager em = EMFService.get().createEntityManager();
    // Read the existing entries
    Query q = em.createQuery("select c from Customer c");
    List<Customer> customers = q.getResultList();
    System.out.println("size : "+customers.size());
    return customers;
  }

  public void add( String name, String desc) {
    synchronized (this) {
      System.out.println("CUSTOMERDAO::add");   
      EntityManager em = EMFService.get().createEntityManager();
      Customer customer = new Customer();
      //customer.setId(new Key());
      customer.setName(name);
      customer.setDesc(desc);
      em.persist(customer);
      System.out.println("name "+ name +" desc "+desc+" created");
      em.close();
    }
  }
//another function
}
```

persistence.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<persistence xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence
    http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_1_0.xsd" version="1.0">

<persistence-unit name="transactions-daniel">
    <provider>org.datanucleus.api.jpa.PersistenceProviderImpl</provider>
    <properties>
        <property name="datanucleus.NontransactionalRead" value="true"/>
        <property name="datanucleus.NontransactionalWrite" value="true"/>
        <property name="datanucleus.ConnectionURL" value="appengine"/>
    </properties>
</persistence-unit>
```

it works fine actually but the problem is sometimes (intermittent) when i inserting new customer, its not immediately update customer list, i need to refresh the page to make sure if my new record successfully inserted. i check in my data store administration page and got my new record there.

--UPDATE
i try to print size every time i call listCustomers and this is proving that its not inserting immediately :

```
CUSTOMERDAO::add
name 4 desc 44 created
size : 4
CUSTOMERDAO::add
name 5 desc 5 created
size : 4
CUSTOMERDAO::add
name 6 desc 6 created
size : 6
```

look after name 5 desc 5 created, the list size still 4 (should be 5 rows). and when i insert another row it works normal again (6 rows).

Comment: Obviously the log tells you what actually happens wrt the datastore. I personally would make reference to it, relative to where your calls to em.persist and em.close are.

Comment: @DataNucleus my log works great. all new record successfully inserted. it just my list on page not updated immediately.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because of the eventual consistent nature of the high replication datastore. Please read this article:
https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/datastore/structuring_for_strong_consistency

The workaround is to have parent keys on the Customer objects and query with that ancestor key, or pass the information of the newly added object and show it.

Comment: Hi do you have example code how to use ancestors keys using Java JPA? Do you mean to create another model class that contains list of customer?

Comment: Sorry, I don't have any sample just right now. Hopefully I will be able to write sample for it in a week or two.